# Why i cannot get POST values?

Tags: php, forms

This is my form, that is dynamically generated:

```
<form action='index.php?direction=saveUserPreferences' method='post'>
<label>Office space<input type='checkbox' name='userInterest[]' value='1' id='1'></label>
<label>Grants<input type='checkbox' name='userInterest[]' value='2' id='2' checked></label>
<label>Loans<input type='checkbox' name='userInterest[]' value='3' id='3'></label>
<label>Events<input type='checkbox' name='userInterest[]' value='4' id='4' checked></label>
<label>Connecting<input type='checkbox' name='userInterest[]' value='5' id='5' checked></label>
<label>Office administration<input type='checkbox' name='userInterest[]' value='6' id='6' checked></label>
<label>TAX<input type='checkbox' name='userInterest[]' value='7' id='7' checked></label>
<label>Self employment<input type='checkbox' name='userInterest[]' value='8' id='8' checked></label>
<label>Start up<input type='checkbox' name='userInterest[]' value='9' id='9' checked></label>
<label>Banks<input type='checkbox' name='userInterest[]' value='10' id='10' checked></label>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name'/>
<input type='submit' name='sendData' value='Save'/>
```

Form points to controller function:

```
   public function saveUserPreferences() {
    var_dump($_POST);

}
```

I tried checking whether post is set etc, and i cannot get array from the post.

I have also login form, that points to the same controller and another function, and it works fine. So i know controller file can and do receive post values.

But for some strange reason, for this particular form i cannot get any values. I have looked up another questions and answers, but cannot get this thing to work.I am also familiar with:
[PHP tutorial about the forms](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html)

Following that solution i get unidentified index error. Is there something i miss?

Thanks in advance for any tips and tricks ;)

08 03 2015
Hey once again. I have no idea if that helps someone by i would like to give an update of what is happening. As you know, i would get nothing from the page, that is when i would echo values in php file, there would be nothing. Yet, in the firebug and chrome developer tools (in the headers and response part of network section) i was able to see actual response. So what i did is this: created a demo table in database, and tried to insert values that i should see from the form into database. And weirdly enough, it did worked. So, don't ask me how is it possible, since i have no idea, yet. So i decided to work based on the responses from developer tools and firebug. And current path of my data is this. View->Controller->Model (post data to array variable) -> dao class->database. Ok, thanks all for viewing and commenting on that one. Thanks

Comment: I have an index.php file with just _var_dump($_POST, $_GET);_ followed by your html form in it. Notice, no  'saveUserPreferences' function. It works as you would expect and shows the form data when the 'save' is pressed. To start to debug your code, i would start as i did here by ensuring that index.php is getting to run. Then i would ensure the correct controller code is being executed. btw, the form needs a closing tag, however, that is not the cause of any issues here as the browser adds it.

Comment: hey. thanks for the input. my index file gets data and is posted to the controller that moves data to the model. i can see that data in firebug. Here is my model funciton :    public function saveUserInterests() {
        echo "<p>This is model</p>";
        foreach ($_POST['userInterest'] as $row) {
                echo "<span>".$row.", </span>";
        }
    } and in the firebug  i see: This is model
2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, so i see that data gets passed correctly. well, model echo gets displayed, so ultimately correct code gets executed. it is really weird issue....

Comment: here are the screen grabs: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/84905 and http://www.pasteall.org/pic/84906

Answer (score 0):

Is there a redirect before reaching the controller? POST data does only exist for the next request so if  you submit to /redirect.php that takes you to /controller.php, $_POST would be empty.

Also your checkboxes doesn't seem right to me. A normal checkbox is like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike
```

So the name is what the checkbox "is about", and the value it's own unique value. The [] is only for select boxes.

Comment: Well, controller file is the very next file where data lands. I am confused about this, since my login form is constructed exactly same way, and it does work. Meaning, i do receive post data from login form. Thanks

Comment: after looking once again on that, you are right. data lands on index.php and then it goes to controller. but, data from login is also post and travels same way, and in controller post data is accessible... weird ;)

Comment: Then check if $_POST contains your data in index.php first. If index.php just redirects to another method there is no problem, it's just when you use header('Location: url')

Comment: If you click on the link in my question (that has been recommended by someone), you will see that [ ] can be used with checkboxes. I want these to be an array. And the values are unique. These are ids of these interests in db. Each has different value.